# Route in rails with simple regex doesn't match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, routes

I looked on the web for a while but I can't get this to work. Our application has to work with urls like ourapp.com/meandyou, where the common element is the "and" in the parameter.
I saw that it's possible to constrain urls parameters using regex, so I added the rule to routes.rb, but without success. If I try to match the same expression using the terminal, it works. Here's the complete route file:

```
Railroot::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :couples

  get "home/index"

  root :to => 'home#index'

  match ':url' => 'couples#show_url', :url => /and/
end
```

I read that Rails nests the expression within a bigger one when matching the route, so maybe I'm doing something slightly wrong even for such a simple expression.

I'm running on Ubuntu 10.04, Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.3, Passenger 3.0.13, Nginx 1.2.1.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

*This should be your starting point:*

```
Railroot::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'home#index'
  resources :couples
  match ':url' => 'couples#show_url', :constraints => { :url => /and/ }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Omega. Unfortunately still no joy. My routes.rb now looks exactly the way you wrote it, but I keep getting "No route matches [GET] "/meandyou"". For the moment I'm using a "catch all" route and use that to trigger the show_url action, but I know it's not very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

This may be your answer, from the [rails routing docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints):

> :constraints takes regular expressions with the restriction that regexp anchors can’t be used. [...]
>   However, note that you don’t need to use anchors because all routes are anchored at the start.

So I think what you are actually matching against is not `/and/` but `/^and/`, which would explain why it's not working.

Try being more explicit, like this:

```
match ':url' => 'couples#show_url', :url => /.*and/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for being late coming back to you. I tried this new expression, but still not working :(.

Comment: @shioyama answer works for me, but I'd hone in the regex with /[^\/]+and.+/